# How to extract coefficients of variables in a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic-math

Suppose I have the matrix below:

```
syms x y z
M = [x+y-z;2*x+3*y+-5*z;-x-y6*z];
```

I want to have the a matrix consisting the coefficients of the variables x,y, and z:

```
CM = [1,1,-1;2,3,-5;-1,-1,6];
```

If I multiply `CM` by `[x;y;z]`, I expect to get `M`.

**Edit**

I have a system of ODE:

```
(d/dt)A = B
```

`A` and `B` are square matrices. I want to solve these set of equations. I don't want to use ode solving commands of Matlab.
If I turn the above set of equations into:

```
(d/dt)a = M*a
```

then I can solve it easily by the eigen vectors and values of matrix M. Here `a` is a column vector containing the variables, and M is the matrix of coefficient extracted from B.

Comment: Or if you're using the Symbolic Math Toolbox: `[diff(M,x) diff(M,y) diff(M,z)]`. I couldn't find a proper gradient in 2 minutes searching; for 3 variables this can do.

Comment: The actual number of variables is 64. I need to do this automatically.

Comment: @Daniel I do not want to get the solution. Both `CM` and `M` are 3by3.

Comment: Why vote down? Please mention the reason. I do not think the question is trivial. Please read the question again.

Comment: @Daniel. Right. I have M and the vector `[x,y,z]`. I do not have CM. I want to obtain it. The code you suggest cannot give it.

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question. Is Andras Deak right in his understanding that x, y and z are symbolic variables?

Comment: @MOON: I think your question is unclear, especially in the symbolic aspect, which might merit the downvote.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, x,y,and z are symbolic variables.

Comment: @MOON did you see my answer then?

Comment: I added the [tag:symbolic-math] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to be using the Symbolic Math Toolbox, you should `diff` symbolically, saving the derivative with respect to each variable:

```
syms x y z;
M=[x+y-z;2*x+3*y-5*z;-x-y+6*z];
Mdiff=[];
for k=symvar(M)
   Mdiff=[Mdiff diff(M,k)];
end
```

Then you get

```
Mdiff =

[  1,  1, -1]
[  2,  3, -5]
[ -1, -1,  6]
```

If you want to order the columns in a non-lexicographical way, then you need to use a vector of your own instead of `symvar`.

### Update

Since you mentioned that this approach is slow, it might be faster to use `coeffs` to treat `M` as a polynomial of its variables:

```
 syms x y z;
 M=[x+y-z;2*x+3*y-5*z;-x-y+6*z];
 Mdiff2=[];
 varnames=symvar(M);

 for k=1:length(M)
    Mdiff2=[Mdiff2; coeffs(M(k),varnames(end:-1:1))];
 end
```

Note that for some reason (which I don't understand) the output of `coeffs` is reversed compare to its input variable list, this is why we call it with an explicitly reversed version of `symvar(M)`.

Output:

```
>> Mdiff2

Mdiff2 =

[  1,  1, -1]
[  2,  3, -5]
[ -1, -1,  6]
```

As [@horchler pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543207/how-to-extract-coefficients-of-variables-in-a-matrix-in-matlab#comment54874568_33543661), this second solution will not work if your symbolic vector has varying number of variables in its components. Since speed only matters if you have to do this operation a lot of times, with many configurations of the parameters in your `M`, I would suggest constructing `M` parametrically (so that the coefficients are also `sym`s) is possible, then you only have to perform the first version once. The rest is only substitution into the result.

Comment: For large number of variable it becomes slow, for example for 64 variable sit takes 1 seconds. Because I have to iterate many times for different parameters it becomes really slow. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The second method only works if every element of `M` is a function of the same full set of variables. Also, it might be a good idea to preallocate `Mdiff` and `Mdiff2` as symbolic matrices.

Comment: @horchler thanks, I didn't notice that about the variables. And of course you're right about pre-allocation; the reason I didn't preallocate is that in my first solution I don't explicitly use an index, and it was simpler to construct `Mdiff` by concatenation. Anyway, one should do this computation once (with the first, more general solution) with parametric matrices, then use that result for various values of the parameters. Symbolic math is not known for being quick.

Comment: Indeed elements of `M` are not a function of the same full set of variables.

Comment: @MOON any chance of defining your matrix parametrically, so that you don't have to extract the parameters for every matrix separately?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I defined it para metrically as you suggested. Before using `eig` to get the eigen values and vectors, I have to convert the resulting matrix into a double. This part takes 5 minutes which is really long for me.

Comment: @MOON I suggest using a parametric function, use my first solution to obtain a matrix depending on the parameters, then use [`matlabFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to convert it into a numerical matrix. Then you can `eig` it numerically, if the symbolic `eig` takes too long for you. Otherwise, use `matlabFunction` on the final result, and evaluate the numeric function at various parameters.